# Heroku database restore fails saying multiple apps but app was included in restore command

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Here's the console where you can see I included and confirmed the app

```html
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:ereader-authors Ryan$ heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://www...._july2018.backup' HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL --app ereader-authors-staging --confirm ereader-authors-staging
Starting restore of https://www...._july2018.backup to gazing-merrily-7879... done

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup will continue restoring.
Use heroku pg:backups to check progress.
Stop a running restore with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Restoring... !
 ▸    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 ▸    
 ▸    waiting for restore to complete
 ▸    pg_restore finished with errors
 ▸    waiting for download to complete
 ▸    download finished with errors
 ▸    please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
 ▸    
 ▸    Run heroku pg:backups:info r008 for more details.
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:ereader-authors Ryan$ heroku pg:backups:info r008
 ›   Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
 ›      Usage: --remote staging
 ›         or: --app ereader-authors-staging
 ›      Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
 ›      Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
 ›      Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
 ›      Heroku remotes in repo:
 ›      ereader-authors (heroku)
 ›   ereader-authors-staging (staging)
 ›
 ›      https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments
```

This used to work, I had this command saved.

This site is making me type more apparently so I can't submit this question.  This add more details error is obnoxious when you're trying to post the console output and they should really revise the way they do this as sometimes you really don't need a giant explanation for a command line.

Answer (score 2):

The error Heroku gives is incorrect if anyone else runs into this, the URL I had was a public share that decided to serve up a web page instead of the file.  The application had nothing to do with it, I switched hosts and then it worked.